# full width responsive equal spacing horizentale menubar bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, css, html, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi i have menu bar like this

**This is my HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Business Casual Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Add custom CSS here -->
    <link href="css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>




    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Info Dubai</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/todoBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;ToDo</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/dineBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Dining</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/shopBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Shooping</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/todoBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;NightLife</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/fashionBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Fashion</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/bodyBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Body&Mind </a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/eventBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/exclusiveBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Exclusive</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><span><img src="images/tarvelBtn.png"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Travel</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>


    <!-- /.container -->



    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**here is the css**

```
hr {
  border-color: #999999;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.brand,
.address-bar {
  display: none;
}


.navbar-brand {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.navbar-nav {
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.img-full {
  min-width: 100%;
}

.brand-name {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}

.tagline-divider {
  margin: 15px auto 3px;
  border-color: #999999;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.box {
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 30px 15px;
}

.intro-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.img-border {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  border: #999999 solid 1px;
}

.img-left {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

footer {
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

footer p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

.brand {
  display: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.top-divider {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.img-left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.address-bar {
  display: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 40px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.navbar {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-header {
  display: none;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
  background:#FFF;
  background: #323132;
  border: none;
}

.nav>li>a {
  /*padding: 35px;*/
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  line-height:normal;
}

.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  font-size: 0.99em;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .box:after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#FFF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #FFF !important;
  background-color: #DD9B26 !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #999 !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #CCC !important;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  max-height: 340px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  background-color:#323132;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

but I want this kind of menu bar 
![enter image description here][2]
but not successful. I want to make full width equal space `li` horizontal menu bar if any body have idea or trick please share with me
responsive

Comment: your image was not attached..

Comment: For responsive try to use bootstrap grid.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve. Please try to make your question clearer. Also, as @SidM pointed out, your image isn't correctly attached. I would also suggest using jsfiddle or a similar service to display your code. It will help you get more and better help.

Comment: right mr @Joum but i have no high rating so thats why i cant post images right now

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question to be that you want make each of the navigation links equal widths and span the entire width of the browser.  If that's correct, you can use this example to produce the equal width navigation links: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/#

To make the navigation span the entire width of the browser, you need to change the container to container-fluid.  In the example above, that would mean replacing the `<div class="container">` just below the `<body>` tag with `<div class="container-fluid">`.

To use what you have so that you can get the toggle effect as well:

1. Change the `<div class="container">` to `<div class="container-fluid nav-container">`
2. Then you'll need to add a rule to your media query to remove the padding from the container-fluid ABOVE 768px
3. You'll need to then set the width of your nav links to 11.1111% each (100%/9).  Again, you'll have to do this in your media-query for min-width: 768px
4. Next, you'll need to set the width of the navbar-nav class to 100% in your same media query to 100%
5. Finally, remove the padding you added left and right to the .navbar-collapse in the media query for 1200px and above and set it to 0 in your media-query for min-width: 768px

So, your css would look like this instead.  NOTE that you will definitely have to play with the font-sizes or images in order to get all of the menu items to fit neatly on one line if that is what you want at all screen widths.  On my screen some of the links begin to break on to the next line at 1228px!

```
hr {
  border-color: #999999;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.brand,
.address-bar {
  display: none;
}


.navbar-brand {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.navbar-nav {
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.img-full {
  min-width: 100%;
}

.brand-name {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}

.tagline-divider {
  margin: 15px auto 3px;
  border-color: #999999;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.box {
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 30px 15px;
}

.intro-text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.img-border {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  border: #999999 solid 1px;
}

.img-left {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

footer {
  background: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

footer p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

.nav-container {padding: 0;}
.navbar-nav>li {width: 11.111111%;}
.navbar-nav {width: 100%;}
.navbar-collapse {padding: 0;}

.brand {
  display: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px 0 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.top-divider {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.img-left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.address-bar {
  display: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 40px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.navbar {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-header {
  display: none;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
  background:#FFF;
  background: #323132;
  border: none;
}

.nav>li>a {
  /*padding: 35px;*/
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  line-height:normal;
}

.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  font-size: 0.99em;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .box:after {
        content: '';
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#FFF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #FFF !important;
  background-color: #DD9B26 !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #999 !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #CCC !important;
}
.navbar-collapse {
  max-height: 340px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  background-color:#323132;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: does the link you provided above can work with toggle mean support toggling

Comment: No, that example doesn't use the toggle.  I'll edit my answer with a suggestion for you.